# JS : объект - ссылочный тип и функция hasOwnProperty

Tags: javascript, объекты

```
let o1={x:500}
console.log(o1.hasOwnProperty("x"))  // true
let o2=o1
console.log(o2.hasOwnProperty("x")) //true
```

объект  - ссылочный тип  . то есть в данном примере o2
содержит указатель `(*o1)` на адрес в памяти в котором находятcя данные  {x:500}
а если так то почему o2.hasOwnProperty("x") - true

Comment: [Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

Comment: Если вы хотите в терминах указателей (что немного не так в JS), то o1 и o2 оба ссылаются на одну и ту же область памяти в которой собственно и лежит объект.

Comment: а почему он не должен быть `true` - если `o1` и `o2` - одно и то же у тебя?

Comment: Записывая `o2.hasOwnProperty` вы обращаетесь не к ссылке, а к объекту, на который она ссылается. Ну и никаких указателей и адресов в JS нет. Они могут использоваться в движке, который это все выполняет, но это происходит непрозрачно для кода.

Comment: @user7860670
но при этом 

`
function A() {}
A.prototype.p1=100
let b = new A();
console.log(b.hasOwnProperty("p1"))      // false
`

мы тоже обращаемся через указатель к объекту

Comment: ¿Почему "тоже"? Ни в коде в вопросе, ни в коде в комментарии, нет никаких указателей. Не стоит путать С++, где `new` возвращает указатель, и js.